# Method overloading not working as expected with Java generics

Tags: java, generics

I have a generic class:

```
public class Facet<C extends Component>
{
    private final C child;

    public Facet(C child) { this.child = child; }

    public C getChild() { return this.child; }

    public UIComponent getViewComponent() {
        return PrimeFacesComponentFactory.create(facesContext, this.getChild());
    }
}
```

I have a component factory that also has a bunch of methods, several of which look like this:

```
public static UIComponent create(FacesContext fc, Component component) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Method not yet implemented for class: " + component.getClass().getName());
}

public static UIRow create(FacesContext fc, Row modelRow) { ... }

public static UIColumn create(FacesContext fc, Column modelColumn) { ... }
```

**NOTE:** in each of the factory methods the 2nd argument is an object that extends Component and what is returned is always a subclass of UIComponent.  The first factory method (the one that throws the exception) is intended to be a "catch all," which is invoked if there is no specific factory method written for a particular component.

What I'm trying to do: the correct factory method should be invoked depending on what type of component facet's child is.  What's happening is that the first factory method is *always* invoked (e.g. the one that throws the exception).  This is counterintuitive to me, since the type of C is known at runtime and C is "some specific type that extends Component."

Debugging, I set a breakpoint at `Facet#getViewComponent`, invoking it when I knew that `facet.getChild()` would return an object of type Row.  So in this example C was Row.  It surprised me to see that when the factory method was invoked e.g.

```
PrimeFacesComponentFactory.create(facesContext, facet.getChild());
```

program execution flowed to the "catch all" factory method! If, however, I explicitly cast facet.getChild() as follows:

```
PrimeFacesComponentFactory.create(facesContext, (Row)facet.getChild());
```

then the specific method was invoked.  Weird, because I simply/redundantly cast a Row to a Row.

I've read [some about why this is happening](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8484670/984932), but it's still hazy and counterintuitive to my mind.  At any rate, how can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Can you show the declaration of `facet` before calling `create(..)`? Or did you mean `this.getChild()`?

Comment: Oh, right!  I did a lot of code simplification to make the example more straightforward and, yes, instead of `facet.getChild()` it should simply be `this.getChild()` as you suggest.  I'll update the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The overload resolution happens once, at compile-time, for the `Facet` class, not for each `C` in `Facet<C>`, and not at run time. A potential solution is to make your catch-all method smarter:

```
public static UIComponent create(FacesContext fc, Component component) {
    if (component instanceof Row)
        return create(fc, (Row)component);
    else if (component instanceof Column)
        return create(fc, (Column)component);
    // include other types, and lastly
    else
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Method not yet implemented for class: " + component.getClass().getName());
}
```

Comment: Great idea.  However, I'm hoping for something without so many if-else-ifs as there are so many components.  Perhaps using a visitor...

Comment: The advantage of visitor is fewer (as in 0) casts, but certainly not fewer lines.

Comment: @JudgeMental I would be able to remove all if/else-ifs from the "catch all" method if I use a visitor, which would be fewer lines.

Comment: well, you would need a `Visitor` interface, an `accept( Visitor )` method in each subclass, and your if/else-if clauses would become implementations of the `Visitor` interface methods in a new class.  I'm curious to see how this could be achieved more tersely than that.

Comment: @JudgeMental You are right.  I should think it through and write some code before I speak next time :)  I did write the visitor and as you indicated it eliminated the need for casts.  Another side benefit: because each Component must implement `accept(Visitor)` when I add a new component to the API in the future the code won't compile unless I update the visitor, which ensures no `UnsupportedOperationException` will be thrown.  Thanks for your patience.  Thanks for nudging me in the right direction.

Comment: I tend to use Visitors when faced with variant type use-cases, for the reasons you give.  But I chafe every time at how much needless verbosity is required where in a language like Scala variants (case classes) and much more (pattern matching) is built in to the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

With the following declaration

```
public C getChild() { return this.child; }

public UIComponent getViewComponent() {
    return PrimeFacesComponentFactory.create(facesContext, facet.getChild());
}
```

assuming `facet` is meant to be `this`, at compile time, the only thing that is known about the type parameter `C` is that it extends `Component`. So the compiler binds this method call with the method declared to accept a `Component`.

```
public static UIComponent create(FacesContext fc, Component component) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Method not yet implemented for class: " + component.getClass().getName());
}
```

Comment: Thanks I've updated the question.  `facet.getChild()` is incorrect.  It should be 'this.child'.

Comment: @PatrickGarner Right. So this is why it happens. As for a solution, check out Tim's. I might attempt something, but no time now.